# Is Selenium a good piece of testing software to use?

Tags: testing, selenium

On my last project, I created some test cases through [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), then automated them so they would run on every build launched from [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).  It worked fantastic, and was consistent for about a month.

Then the tests started failing.  It was, most times, timing issues which caused the failures.  After about two weeks of effort put in over the course of the next two months, it was decided to drop the Selenium tests.  They should have been passing, but the responses and timing of the web application were varying to the extent to which tests would fail when they should have passed.

Did you have a similar experience?  Is Selenium still a good tool to use for Web Application testing?

Comment: depends on the application... is it heavily javascript-based, or just plain-ish html?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Selenium is great tool for web testing, although it's important to make sure your tests are reliable. Timing issues are common, so I would suggest the following:

- Make sure you set a sensible timeout value. I find between 1-2 minutes works well.
- Don't have pauses in your tests - they are the main cause for timing issues. Instead use the waitFor* commands. The waitForCondition is **very** useful
- Identify external calls that can cause timeouts and block that traffic from the machine running tests. You can do this on a firewall level or simply redirect the domain to localhost in your hosts file.

**Update:**

You should also consider using Selenium Grid. It wont directly help with your timeouts, but it can provide a quicker feedback loop for your failures. If you're using TestNG to run your tests you can get it to automatically rerun failures - this gives the tests failing due to timeouts a second chance.

Answer (score 1):

At my previous job we investigated using it as a test tool but found it too fussy to bother integrating into our process. Pretty much the same experience as you.

This was two or three years ago in version 0.8 or so though, I would have expected it to get better since then.

Comment: Selenium has certainly improved since 0.8. Version 1.0 was released earlier this year, after over 12 months in beta.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar experience.  We created a project that would bootstrap a selenium proxy and run an automated suite of tests, but unfortunately it clashed with our build server in a huge way.  There were too many browser inconsistencies and third party dependencies for us to reliably add it to our build.  It was also too slow for us, and added too much time to our builds.

Most of the errors we would run into would be timeouts.

We ended up keeping the project and use it for integration tests on major releases.  The bootstrapping code that we used has proved invaluable in other areas as well.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to be run **after a nightly build** when there's the time for it.  It, or Watin, coulod be integrated with your build scripts.

Very much depends on your team, but if you've a small testing team this can be priceless for picking up some very obvious **runtime issues**.

I'd keep the scope modest and really use them for some **sanity testing** that at least each page can load.

Answer (score 1):

I did have a similar experience with Selenium. We had a legacy system which we built a sort of testing framework around so that we could test the changes we were making. This worked great at the start but eventually some of the earlier tests began to fail (or take too long to run) so we started to turn off more and more of the tests.

To fix some of the issues we stopped selenium from opening and closing a browser for each test i.e. the tests were broken up into blocks and for each *block* of tests the browser would only be opened once. This reduced the time taken to run the tests from several hours to 30 minutes.

Despite the issues I think Selenium is a great tool for testing web-based applications. Many of the problems we experienced centered on the fact that the system we were testing was a legacy system. If you like test-driven development then Selenium fits in very well with that development practice.

EDIT:
Another good thing about Selenium is the ability to track what developer introduced the error as well as where the error is (source file). This makes life so much easier when it comes to fixing the error.

Answer (score 1):

We initially tried to use selenium on our build machine but tests were very brittle and we found we spent a lot of time trying to keep old tests running when changes occurred to unrelated functionality accessed through the same set of pages.  We were automating the tests through nunit.

I would use selenium more as a customer acceptance and integration testing tool.  I'd agree with using it for a nightly build on functionality that is stable.

Answer (score 1):

At a first glance, Selenium looks great. Unfortunately, as sometimes happens with open source projects, they rush to implement new features instead of making it more stable.